# How to find directories to which the owner and group has defined rights?

Tags: linux, bash, find

I would like search in a given tree directory directories to which the **owner** of the directory
(not necessarily the user executing the script) has the right to *read*, but do not have *write* **or** *execute* permission, **and** the owner **group** has the right to *read*.

what i have done so far:

```
find $1 -perm u+r -perm /u+wx ! -perm g+x
```

$1=provided argument to the script

Comment: See `man find` and `-user`, `-group`.

Comment: -user uname File is owned by user uname; -group gname File belongs to group gname. thats all what man offer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
find $1 -type d ! -perm /u+wx -perm /u+r -perm /g+r
```

I think the reason your command wasn't working was because of the lack of a `/` in the last part - `-perm g+x` is telling `find` to match entries with *exactly* permissions 010. (Also, you said you wanted the group to be able to read, not execute).